# Odd behaviour for Tkinter Canvas STATE with time.sleep

Tags: python, tkinter, sleep

I have a Canvas called _their_grid, which has many associated events tied to mouse clicks. I am disabling it upon a certain condition for 10 seconds. Below is the relevant code.

```
        print "not your turn"
        # disable opponent's grid during their turn
        self._their_grid.config(state=DISABLED)
        time.sleep(10)
        self._their_grid.config(state=NORMAL)
        print "now you can go"
```

However, during the ten-second sleep, I still manage to trigger the events. This should not be the case, as state=DISABLED should shut off all the events. The code below, with sleep commented out, stops all events.

```
        print "not your turn"
        # disable opponent's grid during their turn
        self._their_grid.config(state=DISABLED)
        #time.sleep(10)
        #self._their_grid.config(state=NORMAL)
        #print "now you can go"
```

Why do I get this odd behaviour with time.sleep?

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep() doesn't prevent events from being accepted, it simply prevents them from being processed. Every time you click while your app is sleeping the events are simply added to the queue, and processed when the sleep is done sleeping.

You should almost *never* call sleep in a GUI. What you should do instead is set the state to disabled, then schedule resetting the state for ten seconds later:

```
def re_enable(self):
    self._their_grid.config(state=NORMAL)
...
self.after(10000, self.re_enable)
```

Comment: However, when a widget is disabled and you try to trigger any bound event (e.g. click on a disabled button), it is not processed when the widget is enabled again. What is the difference with `time.sleep()`?

Comment: @A.Rodas: time.sleep does exactly what it says: it causes your app to sleep. The OS still delivers events to the app and its widgets, but the app can't respond because it s sleping. When it wakes up, it processes whatever is in the event queue. Setting the state to disabled instructs the event loop to ignore certain events.

Comment: @BryanOakley But there should be no "queued" events once the Canvas is disabled, which happens before the app goes to sleep. So when it "wakes up", why are there queued events?

Comment: You disable the widget, then immediately sleep. If you type on he window, the events are queued up because the app is asleep. Once you are done sleeping, and before the app has a chance to process the events, you immediately re-enable the widget. Once he function exits and the event loop is re-entered, the widget is no longer disabled, and there are events queued up that need to be processed.